# SQL moving aggregate SUM without partial results

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Assume I have this schema (tested on postgresql) where the 'Scorelines' relation contains results of sport matches. (kickoff is a TIMESTAMP but replaced by INT for readability)

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/52475/3

```
CREATE TABLE Scorelines (
   team TEXT, 
   kickoff INT,
   scored INT,
   conceded INT
);
```

Now I want to produce another column 'three_matches_scored' that contains the sum of the points scored
over the 3 preceding game (determined by kickoff) of the same team. I have this:

```
SELECT team, kickoff, scored, conceded, SUM(scored) OVER three_matches AS three_matches_scored 
FROM Scorelines
WINDOW three_matches AS
      (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY kickoff
       ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
ORDER BY kickoff;
```

This works beautifully so far, except that I get values starting from the second game. Example:

```
| TEAM | KICKOFF | SCORED | CONCEDED | THREE_MATCHES_SCORED |
|------|---------|--------|----------|----------------------|
|    A |       1 |      1 |        0 |               (null) |
|    B |       2 |      1 |        1 |               (null) |
|    A |       3 |      1 |        1 |                    1 |
|    A |       4 |      3 |        0 |                    2 |
|    B |       4 |      1 |        4 |                    1 |
|    A |       6 |      0 |        2 |                    5 |
|    B |       6 |      4 |        2 |                    2 |
|    B |       8 |      1 |        2 |                    6 |
|    B |      10 |      1 |        1 |                    6 |
|    A |      11 |      2 |        1 |                    4 |
```

I want the column 'three_matches_scored' to be (null) for the first 3 games because there are no 3 results to sum up. How can I achieve this?

I'd prefer simple understandable solutions, performance is not critical for this particular case.

My only idea right now, is to define a stored function SUM3, that results in (null) with less than 3 values to add up. But I never defined a function in SQL and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case statement to null the rows where there are less than 3 games:

```
SELECT team, kickoff, scored, conceded,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(scored) OVER three_matches = 3 
    THEN SUM(scored) OVER three_matches 
    ELSE NULL 
    END AS three_matches_scored
FROM Scorelines
WINDOW three_matches AS
(PARTITION BY team ORDER BY kickoff
ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
ORDER BY kickoff;
```

Output:

```
 team | kickoff | scored | conceded | three_matches_scored
------+---------+--------+----------+----------------------
 A    |       1 |      1 |        0 |
 B    |       2 |      1 |        1 |
 A    |       3 |      1 |        1 |
 A    |       4 |      3 |        0 |
 B    |       4 |      1 |        4 |
 A    |       6 |      0 |        2 |                    5
 B    |       6 |      4 |        2 |
 B    |       8 |      1 |        2 |                    6
 B    |      10 |      1 |        1 |                    6
 A    |      11 |      2 |        1 |                    4
(10 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

See harmics answer above.

(my first solution, just for reference)

Solution with user defined aggregate:

```
CREATE TYPE intermediate_sum AS (
   sum INT,
   count INT
);


CREATE FUNCTION sum_sfunc(intermediate_sum, INTEGER) RETURNS intermediate_sum AS
$$ SELECT $2 + $1.sum AS sum, $1.count - 1 AS count $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE FUNCTION sum_ffunc(intermediate_sum) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$ SELECT (CASE WHEN $1.count > 1 THEN null
                WHEN $1.count = 0 THEN $1.sum
           END)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE AGGREGATE sum3(INTEGER) (
    sfunc = sum_sfunc,
    finalfunc = sum_ffunc,
    stype = intermediate_sum,
    initcond = '(0,3)'
);
```

The aggregate SUM3 wants at least 3 values, otherwise it returns (null). One can define other aggreates like SUM4 by changing the initcond, for example to '(0,4)'.